# When counting function points, is my website menu an External Input?

Tags: fpa, function-point

I'm doing a [function point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point) count for a large website. Does the main website menu count as an External Input?

I'm doing a function point count as described in [this article](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32094#EIs).

If so, since you only click on one menu item at a time, I assume the number of DETs == 1?

Comment: Hi Willem, don't worry about the downvotes, the community already took care of that ;) Can you edit your question to tell us which FPA method you are using? I _think_ menu items qualify as external input, they are elementary processes that control information outside the boundaries of the application (but I could be horribly wrong, last time I concerned myself with FPA was over a decade ago). You might be interested in the [Function Point Counting Practices Manual](http://perun.pmf.uns.ac.rs/old/repository/research/se/functionpoints.pdf) (warning: PDF)

Comment: Thanks Yannis. I clarified the question a little. I don't know of different types of function point counts, but hopefully that article will clarify.

Comment: From the linked document, pg 65: "A data element type is a unique user recognizable, non-repeated field."  My instinct, further supported by this suggests to me that a menu group would be one function point, and not each menu item.  A set of radio buttons that all share and operate on the the same exclusivity would be one function point. And so on...but I have rather ancient experience doing this kind of analysis, so thats about all the further I can help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes a menu is an external input from the user that gives control information.
I also agree that this is DETs == 1 since it gives you one low complexity data item: the destination of the navigation.